# Visual Studio Web Deployment project auto compress js and css

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, plugins, compression

Is there a way to make the web deployment project automatically compress js and css files when building it? how can I automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by adding an MSBuild task to your web deployment project that would compress your JS and CSS for you.  [Here is an example](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20MSBuild.xml%20File&ProjectName=yuicompressor) using the YUI compressor.

You could also do something similar with other compression libraries by using the [Exec MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) to execute a command line compression tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a build server (Team Build or something else) you can probably find, or certainly build, a custom task to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Pithy is what we use.

http://github.com/clearwavebuild/Pithy/tree/2009.12.22.1000

Has nice preprocessor support, too. (dotlesscss)

Comment: Actually, I misread... this solution does is on the fly, not at build time.